# Silverstripe admin column sort not working on price.nice

Tags: php, silverstripe

Silverstripe 3.6 admin column sort not working on price.nice. I have the following code

```
 private static $summary_fields = array (
    'GridThumbnail'           => '',
    'PricePerNight.nice'      => 'Price',
    'Title'                   => 'Title',
    'Status'                  => 'Status',
    'Proptype.Title'          => 'Type',
    'Pricetype.Title'         => 'Type',
    'Bedrooms'                => 'Beds',
    'NiceDate.Nice'           => 'Updated',
    'CreatedDate'             => 'Added',
    'FeaturedOnHomepage.nice' => 'Featured?'
);
```

When I use the PricePerNight.nice it take the sorting column up and down out when I remove this it allows the sorting column any ideas how to get around this or is it a bug? Basically any column which has the .nice doesn't sort.

Comment: Is this case sensitive? You have `'PricePerNight.nice'` and `'FeaturedOnHomepage.nice'` but also `'NiceDate.Nice'` with a capital **N**

Answer (score 2):

The sorting on the gridfields is provided by the class `GridFieldSortableHeader`. It sorts by using a query. When you call `PricePerNight.nice` you're referring to the method `Nice()` on the class `Currency` which alters the data that comes from the database.

You can fix this by calling the method `setFieldSorting` on `GridFieldSortableHeader`. The method requires an array with your custom fieldnames and the actual fieldname as the value to sort on.

From the code I guess you're following the SilverStripe Lessons and you're working in a ModelAdmin.

For ModelAdmin:

```
public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null)
{
    $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);

    if($gridField = $form->Fields()->dataFieldByName($this->sanitiseClassName($this->modelClass))) {
        $config = $gridField->getConfig();
        $sortableHeader = $config->getComponentByType(GridFieldSortableHeader::class);

        $sortableHeader->setFieldSorting([
            'PricePerNight.nice'      => 'PricePerNight',
            'NiceDate.Nice'           => 'NiceDate',
            'FeaturedOnHomepage.nice' => 'FeaturedOnHomepage'
        ]);
    }

    return $form;
}
```

For DataObjects (pages):

```
public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    if($gridField = $fields->dataFieldByName('Property')) { //relationname
        $config = $gridField->getConfig();
        $sortableHeader = $config->getComponentByType(GridFieldSortableHeader::class);

        $sortableHeader->setFieldSorting([
            'PricePerNight.nice' => 'PricePerNight',
            'NiceDate.Nice' => 'NiceDate',
            'FeaturedOnHomepage.nice' => 'FeaturedOnHomepage'
        ]);
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: So I add this to my page with the GridFieldConfig which is:

<?php
 
class PropertyPage extends Page{

above code

-------------

<?php

class Property extends DataObject {

$summary_fields = array (
'PricePerNight' => 'Price',
'FeaturedOnHomepage' => 'Featured?'

is that correct

Comment: I added an explanation on how to do it in DataObjects such as Pages.